# angular cannot receive emitted value

Tags: angular, select, angular-components, angular-event-emitter

I'm trying to emit value from `DropdownComponent` to `TaskComponent`:

[image]

`DropdownComponent` is located inside of `NavBbrComponent` (`AppModule`) and `TaskComponent` is in `MainComponent` which belongs `HomeModule`.

In `DropdownComponent` there is `select` definition:

```html
<select class="form-control minimal" id="project" name="project" [(ngModel)]="selectedProject" (change)="onChange($event.target.value)">
  <option>Project 1</option>
  <option>Project 2</option>
</select>
```

with `onChange` method which emit value:

```
onChange(event) {
    this.toTask.emit(event);
  }
```

Value is binded in Main Component where is definition of the Task component

```html
<app-task (toTask)="fromDropdown($event)"></app-task>
```

but there is no value in `TaskComponent`.

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kd665m)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your `DropdownComponent` and `TaskComponent` components don't have any kind of a parent child relationship you have to use kind of a service to pass data between these components.

I just updated your <kbd>[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-apj63w?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhome%2Fmain%2Ftask%2Ftask.component.ts)</kbd> and you could be found out solution there.

<kbd>[SAMPLE DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-apj63w?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhome%2Fmain%2Ftask%2Ftask.component.ts)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is completely wrong. Events in Angular is not accessible via Output in components that are not contains them i mean that this one

```
<app-task (toTask)="fromDropdown($event)"></app-task>
```

means that you have `toTask` event inside app-task component and you can access it in you `main-component`.

Right approach to transfer data between components with that relation is to create service and emit values in navbar component to service, and listen  them in your task component. You need to use `Subject` to solve that problem. There is a lot of answers on that down here.